# How to get html tag in Asp.Net Gridview with javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net, gridview

I want to get a select tag in my Gridview with javscript.

E.g :

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
 <PagerTemplate>
   <table>
    <tr>
     <td>
      <select id="Select" runat="server" ></select>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </PagerTemplate>
 </asp:GridView>
```

I want to fill my select tag with Javascript.

I have this :

```
function fillSelectTag(pageNumber) {
 var sel = document.getElementById('Select');
 for (var i = 0; i < pageNumber; i++) {
     var opt = document.createElement('option');
     opt.innerHTML = i;
     opt.value = i;
     sel.appendChild(opt);
 }
 sel.selectedIndex = 0;
}
```

The problem is I have null for `document.getElementById('Select');`.

How to get the select tag?

Comment: you tried adding `.value` ? so the code might look something like this: `document.getElementById("Select").value` ?

Comment: Open your web page in chrome or firefox and right click the element and choose inspect element. Then note the id of the element.Then replace it in you code. Otherwise there is no issue in your code.I have created fiddle with your code http://jsfiddle.net/Midhun52/9cmysqo8/

Comment: @Midhun, thanks it works! And in the CodeBehind, how to get this select tag? I want his selected value. I tried this : `GridView1.BottomPagerRow.FindControl("Select1") as HtmlInputText;` but I have Null.

Comment: I found, replace `HtmlInputText` by `HtmlSelect` and it works.

Comment: Use jQuery for this kind of stuff. Also the ID of the dropdown list won't be "select" in rendered html. try checking the source of your page.

Answer (score 0):

The server id is changed in the html generated by asp.net You need `ClientID`, If you want table in grid you better look at `DataList` or `Repeater`. As you have select in `GridView` and you will have as many `select` as you have `GridView` Rows. You can loop through the DOM to get all the elements that have id containing Select.

```
for(i=0;i<document.forms[0].length;i++)
{
    e=document.forms[0].elements[i];
    if (e.id.indexOf("Select") != -1 )
    {
       alert(e.id);             
    }       
}
```